# Displaying data.frames using grid.arrange

Tags: r, gridextra

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

e <- tableGrob(hg, rows = NULL)

pdf("data_output.pdf", paper = "a4")

grid.arrange(e, e, e, e,ncol=2, nrow=2, top=textGrob("Data", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1.0, gp=gpar(fontsize=20,font=8)))

dev.off()
```

Questions:

- how can the font size of the data in the table be changed?
- how can the white space around the data tables be changed?

[image]

Comment: try this `ggplot2::ggsave('customsize.pdf', arrangeGrob(t <- tableGrob(iris[1:3,1:4], theme = ttheme_default(26)), t, t, t), width=20, height=4)`

Comment: this alters font size without changing padding

Comment: that was for your question re font size; for the padding have you tried changing the padding?

Comment: i decided to edit a theme directly to achieve desired result:
`tt3 <- ttheme_default(
  core=list(fg_params=list(fontsize=6), padding = unit(c(2, 2), "mm")),
  colhead=list(fg_params=list(fontsize=6))
)`,
However I cannot find a suitable command to remove white space between graphs, except  combine(e,e,e,e, along=2) , but this is in 1 direction only.